# I was trying to use e.preventdefault in two different elements is js. But prevent default works only in one . Please help me with this problem?

Tags: javascript

window.onload = function () {

```
document.getElementById("lin").addEventListener("click", function func1(event) {
    console.log('prevent defaul stopped')
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

}

window.onload = function () {

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function func2(event) {
    console.log(' button prevent defaul stopped')
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

}

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which one works and which one doesnt?

Comment: And what type of elements you're dealing with

Comment: My guess would be you're selecting both elements by id but one doesn't have the correct id (has a class with the same name or there would be a typo in the id).

Comment: Why are you assigning two functions to the onload? You could just combine them into one pass

Comment: Also, if you're using `window.onload = function(){}` twice (on the same console), the first one won't work and the second will because you're overriding it. Instead, as @AndrewCorrigan suggested, you can combine the 2 so the code'd be: `window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("lin").addEventListener("click", function func1(event) {
    console.log('prevent defaul stopped')
    event.preventDefault()
});
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function func2(event) {
    console.log(' button prevent defaul stopped')
    event.preventDefault()
});
}`